# Managing dependencies with CloudFormation and CFN-SIGNAL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudformation

This might get a bit convoluted but I'll try to simplify.

I have a `CloudFormation` template setting up 3 identical `EC2` machines, and using `cfn-init` in the `UserData` script it pulls some automation code from `S3`, and runs it to set these machines up in a very product-specific high availability configuration that isn't relevant here.

It looks something like this:

```
"commands" : {
          "0-Tester" : {
            "command" : "echo \"I am OK.\" > \"d:\\test.txt\"",
            "waitAfterCompletion": 5
          },
          "1-Pullcode" : {
            "command" : "aws s3 cp s3://some-bucket/code.zip d:/code.zip > d:/s3sync.log",
            "waitAfterCompletion": 5
          },
          "2-UnpackCode" : {
            "command" : "powershell Expand-Archive -Path d:\\code.zip -DestinationPath d:\\dev",
            "waitAfterCompletion": 5
          },
          "3-ResetLicensing" : {
            "command" : "\"C:/Program Files/something/iisnodeModule/node.exe\" d:/dev/aws-automation/service.js --service Licensing.Service --action restart > d:/oxy_restart.log",
            "waitAfterCompletion": 5
          },
          "4-RunAutomation" : {
            "command" : "\"C:/Program Files/something/iisnodeModule/node.exe\" d:/dev/aws-automation/automate.js --config c:/servers.conf --all > d:/automation.log",
            "waitAfterCompletion": 5
          }
        }
```

For this automation to happen, each machine needs to know the IPs or DNS names of all 3 machines (think creating a mongodb replica set, for example) and to achieve that I've got the template creating 3 DNS records in `Route53` for these EC2s (in a private hosted zone) and generating these 3 predictable DNS names in a file on each EC2 instance.

That happens like so:

```
"config": {
        "files": {
          "c:\\servers.conf": {
            "content": {
              "role": "app",
              "servers": [
                {"Fn::Join": [".",["build1",{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},{"Ref": "HostedZone"}]]},
                {"Fn::Join": [".",["app1",{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},{"Ref": "HostedZone"}]]},
                {"Fn::Join": [".",["app2",{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},{"Ref": "HostedZone"}]]}
              ],
              "replSetName": { "Ref": "ReplicaSetName" },
              "ecFolder": { "Ref": "ElasticubeFolder" }
            }
          }
        },
```

And of course

```
"DNSRecordBuild1": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
  "Properties": {
    "HostedZoneName": {"Ref": "HostedZone"},
    "Name": {
      "Fn::Join": [".",["build1",{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},{"Ref": "HostedZone"}]]
    },
    "Type": "A",
    "TTL": "900",
    "ResourceRecords": [{"Fn::GetAtt": ["build1","PrivateIp"]}]
  }
}
```

To create the DNS records.

So at this point, the stack gets created perfectly - `CFN` spins up the 3 instances, renders a config `json` on each of them with the DNS names that will eventually exist, pulls the code from `S3`, and starts running the scripts. Now the `R53` records obviously depend on these instances to be up, but they are created as soon as the instance is ready, which is **before** the scripts start running - thus by the time the scripts refer to said DNS names, they already exist in `R53`. *This setup works fine.*

Now, I wanted to add an `ELB` to the stack, and I wanted it to be created *only when the 3 machines are fully configured and ready for traffic*. So I've added a `DependsOn` attribute to the `ELB` resource, which worked fine, and then added `cfn-signal` and `CreationPolicy` to each instance to make sure it's marked as done only when the automation scripts finish:

```
"cfn-signal.exe -e %ERRORLEVEL% --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, " --resource build1 --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }
```

and

```
"CreationPolicy" : {
    "ResourceSignal" : {
      "Timeout" : "PT10M"
    }
  }
```

But immediately, this breaks the whole process - because now `R53` records won't get created until the machine sends the `signal` - and the machine won't send it because it's trying to run the scripts that depend on those DNS names and thus fail.

For now I've simply removed the `signal` and `policy` to let the ELB start up as soon as the instances are online, but that's not ideal. So the question is: **how can I delay the creation of the ELB to after the scripts are done, without delaying R53 resources or creating any such dependency loops as above?**

At the moment my thoughts are:

1. Adding a `wait` resource to the template, signalling to it, and having the `ELB` resource `DependsOn` this `wait` - not sure this is even possible or what adverse effects it could have
2. Not creating the `ELB` via `CFN` at all, but rather have it created via the `AWS CLI` on one of the machines when it can verify all other machines are ready. Really dislike this approach as it would require a lot of additional code in my automation scripts and make this resource harder to manage (ie would need to delete the ELB manually when deleting the stack)
3. Have each instance "signal" using an alternative method such as putting a file or flag some where (like S3) and then having a `lambda` react to it and create the ELB - but this has the same disadvantage as #2...

Answer (score 2):

How about attacking it from a completely different angle and use AWS EC2 System Manager (SSM) to configure the instances after all the resources (i.e. 3x EC2, DNS and ELB) are created?

The SSM will depend on the creation of all the above and then login to each instance and start up the app. That should resolve the dependency problems.

Check out [AWS::SSM::Association](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-association.html) and [AWS::SSM::Document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-document.html) for the CloudFormation support of EC2 Systems Manager.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hey, I've started going down that path for a different purpose (automating processes post setup), got SSM to work on my instances and sometime in the near future I'll consider switching the deployment to SSM as well. If/once I do I'll mark this as accepted - just wish there was a better way as *that's what cfn-init is for*.. Thanks again, m8.